# Complex integration given wrong answer by a factor of two

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi } (1+2cost)^{n}cos(nt) dt$$

$$e^{it} = z, izdt = dz$$

$$\oint  (1+e^{it}+e^{-it})^{n}\frac{e^{nit}+e^{-nit}}{2} \frac{dz}{iz} = \oint  (1+z+z^{-1})^{n}\frac{z^{n}+z^{-n}}{2} \frac{dz}{iz}$$

$$\oint  (z+z^{2}+1)^{n}\frac{z^{2n}+1}{z^{2n+1}} \frac{dz}{2i} = \pi Res = \pi \frac{d^{2n}}{(2n)! dz^{2n}}((z+z^{2}+1)^{n}(z^{2n}+1))$$

$$= \pi \sum \begin{pmatrix}
2n\\ \beta 
\end{pmatrix} \frac{d^{\beta} {(z^{2n}+1)}}{dz^{\beta}(2n)!} \frac{d^{2n-\beta}}{dz^{2n-\beta}}(z+z^{2}+1)^{n}$$

Since the pole is at z=0, all terms above vanish apart from $\beta = 2n$, in this case:

$$= \pi \frac{d^{2n} {(z^{2n}+1)}}{(2n)!dz^{2n}} \frac{d^{0}}{dz^{0}}(z+z^{2}+1)^{n} $$
$$= \pi \frac{(2n)!}{(2n)!} (1) = \pi $$

The answer provided by the book is $2 \pi$

I can't really find the error i supposedly did :/

Comment: not sure how you do the derivative but you need the coefficient of $z^{2n}$ in $(1+z+z^2)^n(z^{2n}+1)$ and obviously you get a $1$ from the $z^{2n}$ factor and the $1$ in $(1+z+z^2)^n$ and another $1$ from the coefficient of $z^{2n}$ in $(1+z+z^2)^n$, so the answer is indeed $2\pi$!

Comment: @Conrad i am sorry, but i think i didn't got what you mean. Could you be more detailed? Thank you by the reply

Comment: Since the denominator is $z^{2n+1}$ and the only possible non zero integral is the one with the term $1/z$, it follows that only the term $z^{2n}$ in the numerator matters, so one needs its coefficient and the integral is them $\pi$ times as you noticed (there was  a $1/2$ too)

Comment: Note that when $n=0$ the answer is, trivially, $2\pi$, some evidence in favor of the book.